# как обратиться к item из другого item в toolbar

Tags: java, android, android-toolbar

как обратиться к item из другого item в toolbar?
Например, если я нажимаю на item1, то мне надо изменить item2

```
 @Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {


    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.item_left:

            return true;

        case R.id.item_button:
            // если я нажимаю на этот item, то title'ы item_left и item_right должно поменяться местами

            return true;

        case R.id.item_right:
            return true;

        default:

            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

    }
```

Comment: Можете добавить код, который у вас уже есть? С ним было бы легче понять, какое именно решение посоветовать.

Comment: Все, добавил...

Comment: пытался так: MenuItem ileft = (MenuItem) findViewById(R.Id.item_left); но никак

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно сохранить ссылку на меню в `onCreateOptionsMenu`, а потом через неё обращаться к элементам.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

  private Menu menu;

  //...     

  @Override
  public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);

    //...

    this.menu = menu;
    return true;
  }

  private void changeLeftItem() {
    MenuItem leftItem = menu.findItem(R.id.item_left);
    leftItem.setTitle("Другое название");
  }

}
```

Comment: Можно ли это реализовать в onOptionsItemSelected?

Comment: в  `onOptionsItemSelected` передаётся конкретный `item` из него не получится вытащить `Menu`, поэтому ссылка вытаскивается из `onCreateOptionsMenu` или `onPrepareOptionsMenu`. Но никто же вам не запрещает переопредлить `onOptionsItemSelected` и `onCreateOptionsMenu` в одном классе.

Comment: Не понял с тем как вытащить menu: this.menu = menu;

Comment: Так как написано в ответе переопределяете метод `onCreateOptionsMenu` и там внутри `this.menu = menu;`

Comment: Сообразил. Спасибо!